# Uploading a maven plugin to jFrog

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, jfrog-cli

I have worked on a Maven **plugin** and I need to upload it onto jFrog so that my team can use it. Of course, I can use the `jar` and distribute it but since it is kind of a serious project we chose jFrog as the central repository.

The problem that I'm facing is kind of a confusing one. As said before, when I transfer the plugin (a `jar`) inside a flash drive to another teammate, and run the plugin, it worked perfectly, without any glitch. However, after uploading it to jFrog, and when trying to run the plugin I got this error.

```
[ERROR] Plugin com.XXXX:XXXX:1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.XXXX:XXX:jar:1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I checked my `.m2` directory upon trying do a `mvn clean install` and I haven't got the `.jar` into my `.m2`.

I also tried to get the `.jar` from jFrog as a dependency using `<dependencies> .. </dependencies>` , and the `.jar` was downloaded as expected; however, when I added that `.jar` as a plugin using `<plugin>...</plugin>` configurations, the same error came up.

*In a summary, my plugin works fine in my local machine (and works fine when I transfer the jar without uploading it to jFrog) but gives this error when trying download the `.jar` from jFrog and trying to execute it thereafter.*

It would be a great help if somebody can help me out.

Comment: can you share the command to deploy to jfrog you use? and it would be nice if you have shared pom.xml too maybe in girhub/gist as reproducer

Comment: Hi. I used the jFrog web tool to deploy the jar into it. So didn't use any command. 

Here's the gist for the `pom.xml` for the plugin.
https://gist.github.com/Tashun/4a54c324bd708ce55bce995f08a01a9c

Comment: webtools can be problematic. and not easy to determine what the issue is. just add user credentials to your mvn settings xml and try to deploy from command line. you can fallow http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configuring an additional maven repository, for maven dependencies, a configuration like below is used,

```
   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo-id</id>
            <url>repository-url</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

For maven plugins, a separate configuration has to be added to the `pom.xml` in order to give run the remote repository plugin.

```
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repo-id</id>
            <url>repository-url</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```